# How to use Kotlin compiler library to analyze external project

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-ide

I have a problem with processing Kotlin source code via kotlin-compiler-embeddable. I need to obtain PSI class representations for all classes in an external project, build them, and get BindingContext, but I can't find any examples.

I would like to use the kotlin-compiler-embeddable library to analyse dependencies in a Kotlin project outside the IntelliJ environment.

I manage to obtain PSI representations for individual classes. Unfortunately this is not enough. I would like to track dependencies between classes.

```kotlin
private val project by lazy {
        KotlinCoreEnvironment.createForProduction(
            Disposer.newDisposable(),
            CompilerConfiguration(),
            EnvironmentConfigFiles.JVM_CONFIG_FILES
        ).project
    }

    fun createKtFile(codeString: String, fileName: String) =
        PsiManager.getInstance(project)
            .findFile(
                LightVirtualFile(fileName, KotlinFileType.INSTANCE, codeString)
            ) as KtFile
```

For example, I need to get a PSI Class representation or fully-qualified class name for the `service` parameter type.

```kotlin
class ShapeEndpoint(service: ShapeService)
```

Is there somewhere a comprehensive example that would show how to compile a group of source files, build a BindingContext, access it and then use it effectively?